# Using regex match string that start with dot excluding doubles

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for a regex to split following string:

`.name "Collector Show Stress" .target "target" .curio_result_type "negative" .chance 80% .stress 10.0  .on_hit true .on_miss false.queue true`

into:

`.name "Collector Show Stress" 
.target "target"
.curio_result_type "negative" 
.chance 80% 
.stress 10.0
.on_hit true 
.on_miss false
.queue true`

I've used following regex to match but it also splits the double:

`\.[^.]+`

The result I get is:

`.name "Collector Show Stress" 
.target "target"
.curio_result_type "negative" 
.chance 80% 
.stress 10
.0
.on_hit true 
.on_miss false
.queue true`

I'm basically a newbie when it comes to regex so any help is appreciated.

I'm using the regex in a C# console app.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match your example data, you could match the available options for the second part:

```
\.[^.\s]+ (?:"[^"]+"|true|false|[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?%?)
```

**Explanation**

- `.[^.\s]+`  Match . and 1+ occurrences of any char except a dot or whitespace char
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `"[^"]+"` Match from the opening till the closing double quote `"..."`
  - `|` Or
  - `true` Match literally
  - `|` Or
  - `false` Match literally
  - `|` Or
  - `[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
  - `%?` Match an optional percentage sign
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c.%5b%5e.%5cs%5d%2b+%28%3f%3a%22%5b%5e%22%5d%2b%22%7ctrue%7cfalse%7c%5b0-9%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5c.%5b0-9%5d%2b%29%3f%25%3f%29&i=.name+%22Collector+Show+Stress%22+.target+%22target%22+.curio_result_type+%22negative%22+.chance+80%25+.stress+10.0++.on_hit+true+.on_miss+false.queue+true)

A less stricter pattern might be to match not a dot, or match a dot when followed by a digit

```
\.[^.]+ (?:[^.\s]|\.(?=[0-9]))+
```

**Explanation**

- `.[^.]+`  Match a dot followed by 1+ times any char except a dot
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[^.\s]` Match any char except a dot or whitespace char
  - `|` Or
  - `\.(?=[0-9])` Match a dot asserting a digit directly to the right
- `)+` Close group and repeat 1+ times

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c.%5b%5e.%5d%2b+%28%3f%3a%5b%5e.%5cs%5d%7c%5c.%28%3f%3d%5b0-9%5d%29%29%2b&i=.name+%22Collector+Show+Stress%22+.target+%22target%22+.curio_result_type+%22negative%22+.chance+80%25+.stress+10.0++.on_hit+true+.on_miss+false.queue+true)

Comment: Second regex did the trick. I tried with some more data and it seems to be consistant. Many thanks! Been trying to figure this out for an hour now